# Использование x:Bind с ViewModel UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Не получается сделать `x:Bind` для `DataTemplate`

```
 <models:EffectModel x:Name="EffectModel" x:Key="EffectModel"/>
```

...

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="{StaticResource EffectModel}">
      <TextBlock      
         Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

`Title` это `public string` свойство.
Постоянно пишет на `Title`, что его нет в контексте `MainPage`. Почему он не обращается к `EffectModel`

```
public class EffectModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Uri FrameImage { get; set; }

}
```

UPD

```
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:EffectModel">
                <Border    
            Width="400"
            Height="240">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush 
                            Stretch="Fill" 
                            ImageSource="{x:Bind FrameImage}"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Хм. А почему `x:DataType="{StaticResource EffectModel}"`, а не `x:DataType="models:EffectModel"`? Может, в этом проблема?

Comment: Так он же вроде уже описан и я по ключу обращаюсь, так нельзя?

Comment: Не, `{StaticResource EffectModel}` — это ж не тип! Это объект. А вам нужен именно тип.

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос. Для картинок не работает, говорит нужен конвертер. Обычный `Binding` работает без всяких конверторов

Comment: Хм. А если через функцию? https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/11510070-x-bind-to-imagesource-support-support-system-uri

Comment: @VladD `ImageSource="{x:Bind ConvertToUri(FrameImage)}"/>` Пытается найти поле ConvertToUri

Comment: @VladD Так эта функция должна быть реализована мной получается В классе Models?

Comment: Я не уверен насчёт того, где оно будет искать эту функцию. В WPF такой фичи вовсе нет :-\

Comment: @VladD Нашел конвертер `uri to imagesource` код работает, но картинки не загружаются

Comment: А конвертер вызывается? Если поставить в нём breakpoint.

Comment: @VladD переписал несного конвертер, и все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае `x:Bind` на свойство типа `string` в `DataTempate`, как подсказал пользователь  VladD, необходимо указать `x:DataType="model:` ***Ваша модель в которой лежит свойство***`"`
В случае с `x:Bind` картинки со страницы на свойство типа `Uri` необходим еще и конвертер.

Код конвертера:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,string culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        if (value is Uri)
            return new BitmapImage((Uri)value);

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

На `Xaml` выглядеть будет следующим образом:

```
ImageSource="{x:Bind FrameImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
```

`ImageConvertor` объявлен в `App.xaml`

Comment: Можно обойтись без конвертера если FrameImage будет типа string, а не Uri.